# Bash script - mass modify files sed regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a set of .csv files (all in one folder) with the format shown below:

```
170;151;104;137;190;125;170;108
195;192;164;195;171;121;133;104
... (a lot more rows) ...
```

The thing is I screwed up a bit and it should look like this

```
170;151;104.137;190.125;170;108
195;192;164.195;171.121;133;104
```

In case the difference is too subtle to notice:

**I need to write a script that changes every third and fifth semicolon into a period in every row in efery file in that folder.**

My research indicate that I have to devise some clever `sed s/` command in my script. The problem is I'm not very good with regular expressions. From reading the tutorial it's probably gonna involve something with /3 and /5.

Comment: +1 since I learned something new by answering it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a really short way to do it:

```
sed 's/;/./3;s/;/./4' -iBAK *
```

It replaces the 3rd and then the 5th (which is now the 4th) instances of the `;` with `.`.

I tested it on your sample (saved as sample.txt):

```
$ sed 's/;/./3;s/;/./4' <sample.txt
170;151;104.137;190.125;170;108
195;192;164.195;171.121;133;104
```

For safety, I have made my example back up your originals as `<WHATEVER>.BAK`.  To prevent this, change `-iBAK` to `-i`.

---

*This script may not be totally portable but I've tested it on Mac 10.8 with BSD sed (no idea what version) and Linux with sed (gsed) 4.1.4 (2003).  @JonathanLeffler notes that it's standard POSIX `sed` as of 2008.  I also just found it and like it a lot.*

---

Golf tip: If you run the command from bash, you can use brace expansion to achieve a supremely short version:

```
sed -es/\;/./{3,4} -i *
```

Comment: This works but only as long as there are exactly 7 semi-colons on the line.  The `.*` expressions are greedy, and will eat semi-colons too if there are extra ones in the data.

Comment: The format was clearly specified in the OQ.  There's all sorts of reasons it might fail apart from that.

Comment: By reasons I mean other changes in the input format.  What if one field starts containing quoted strings with semicolons in it?  What if you get comment lines containing semicolons.  It's good enough as it is.

Comment: That's why you got an up-vote, despite my reservations.  The specification is third and fifth semi-colons; your answer will be fine as long as there are seven, as in the sample data.  The other answer will work on the third and fifth semi-colons even if there is a different number of semi-colons in the line (as long as there are at least 5 semi-colons).

Comment: okay, I found a MUCH better way that's 1/4 of the size and fixes your reservations.

Comment: That's interesting — very interesting.  The numeric flag after the `s` command is specified in POSIX 2008 for [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), but I'd not noticed it before.  It is not part of classic `sed`, so as you note, use caution if you need to port it to the ... staider versions of Unix (Solaris, HP-UX, AIX). I can't up-vote a second time, but I have no real reservations about this answer.

Comment: In Bash, this can be further shortened to: `sed -es/\;/./{3,4} *`

Comment: That is terrific, thank you very much, I was expecting it to look like that. The thing about those regular expressions is, they always look obvious AFTER someone shows them to me :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
sed -i 's/^\([^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*\);\([^;]*;[^;]*\);/\1.\2./' foldername/*
```

(Disclaimer: I did test this, but some details of `sed` are not fully portable. I don't think there's anything non-portable in the above, so it should be fine, but please make a backup copy of your folder first, before running the above. Just in case.)